# some DOM functions are missing from google HTML service

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I recently wanted to re-build my webapp as a google webapp. I found part of my js library does not work when I pasted it as google app script. The main reason for the failure is some dom functions are missing when the javascript is run.

I made an example to show the problem below,

```
<body>
<input type='select' id='test'></input>
<p id='output'></p>
<body>

<script>
var dom = document.getElementById('test');
var outputText = '';
for(var i in dom) outputText += "<br>"+ i +": " + dom[i] + "</br>";
var out = document.getElementById('output');
out.innerHTML = outputText;
</script>
```

When I load this page just by using firefox, one of the functions I can get is,

```
checkValidity: function checkValidity() { [native code] }
```

However, if I load this page by google htmlService, the above function is missing.

I know google scripts run under a 'sandbox' environment, but I double checked my app runs under 'native' mode. I am wondering if there's other configurations that restrict the usage of dom elelemts in google script. Or google simply does not support all of them?

Comment: I don't know if this helps, but have you seen this documentation: [Google Documentation - javascript restrictions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/restrictions#javascript)

Comment: It's best to use this syntax for functions in HTML Script tags:  `window.myFunction = function() { ... };`  and run the function by calling `myFunction`.

Answer (score 1):

As @Sandy Good mentioned, the HTML Service "[sanitizes](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/restrictions)" all code that'll be run client-side using Google Caja. There are two modes, `EMULATED` and `NATIVE`, but in either case, the code is still sanitized; the difference is that in `NATIVE` mode, if you're careful, your code won't necessarily be rewritten. Definitely check out the link he posted.

If you're ever stuck while working with the HTML Service, you can use the [Caja Playground](https://caja.appspot.com/), which gives you more detailed information about what was sanitized.

Comment: Thanks for your link to Playground. I googled for some time. I think the main reason is that google put some restrictions on the dom elements. Just like they did for iframe. Quoted from google - "...some Although embed, iframe, and object elements are technically supported, their content is severely restricted; in practical terms, you cannot use these elements...."

Comment: Absolutely. There are restrictions on many things with Caja. I haven't found that these restrictions are all that well documented, but I can usually determine what's problematic using Caja Playground and a little common sense.